# Not getting cell's value on cell leave in edit mode

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview

I am trying to find cell's value when cell is in edit mode on cell leave event.

```
private void dgvHP_OPDPrescriptionDiagnosis_Detail____CellLeave(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.ColumnIndex == 9)
            {                
                if (CellLeaveStatus == string.Empty)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(dgvHP_OPDPrescriptionDiagnosis_Detail___.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value.ToString());                    
                }
            }
        }
```

`MessageBox` shows empty string when cell is in edit mode but It's working fine when cell is not in edit mode.

Comment: this condition: if (CellLeaveStatus == string.Empty) is one that causing the issue cause it will show you the row only when the edit cell is empty